# Is it possible that Sources.mapJournal() is slow for frequently updating of IMap?

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I'm trying to emulate the stream drawing from `Sources.mapJournal` through IMap which receives data from IoT device. The processing of this stream is too slow and I'm getting the big accumulated outcome after 30-60 seconds.

When I started to update the IMap frequently with small data (12 KB per value), the exception is:

> com.hazelcast.ringbuffer.StaleSequenceException: sequence:123 is too small and data store is disabled.

I increased the default capacity of IMap journal 10 times. It became stable after that, but very slow. A similar issue is when I'm updating the IMap with big values (about 1.2 MB per 5 seconds). Additionally I have several connected IoT devices and each of them has its own Jet job with the same pipeline:

```java
StreamStage<TagPosition> sourceSteam = 
    p.drawFrom(Sources.<TagPosition, String, TagPosition>mapJournal(
        Constants.IMAP_TAGS_POSITIONS_BUFFER,
        Util.mapPutEvents().and(entry -> ((String) entry.getKey()).startsWith(instanceNumber)),
        Util.mapEventNewValue(),
        JournalInitialPosition.START_FROM_OLDEST));

// Drain to SmartMap
sourceSteam.drainTo(SmartMapSinks.newTagPositionSink(instanceNumber));
```

Thanks in advance!

UPD:

- The journal size is EventJournalConfig.DEFAULT_CAPACITY * 10 = 100
  000 (1 partition)
- Jet version is 0.7.2
- Serialazable classes
  implements `com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.IdentifiedDataSerializable`

Comment: Could you give more numbers: the actual frequency of IMap updates, size of the item, cluster size etc. 1.2MB in five seconds isn't "big". What is `SmartMapSinks`? Isn't it the bottleneck?

Comment: What's your journal size? Journal size is per partition, so you need to calculate the journal size per partition as `journalSize / partitionCount`. Also what version of Jet are you using? Another thing to check is what kind of serialization you are using. Plain Java `Serializable` can be quite slow.

Comment: @CanGencer, answered in the description.

Comment: @Oliv, I've tried 500 ms per transaction and plain java foreach loop. Size of checked item was from 12 KB to 1.2MB (different tests). The last bigger size was used when I put List<TagPosition> instead of single element. Cluster size (available xmx) is about 1.7 GB. `SmartMapSink` is just a custom sink for batching of data and send it futher through websocket. I've called the service which `SmartMapSink` wraps directly and there were no delays.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that the one IMap journal are used by several jet jobs?

Comment: @SergeyGranev how many partitions you have? You say 100,000 (1 partition)? But it will actually be 100,000 / 271 entries per partition. Something else you can try is to increase the localParallelism of the source, by default it's set to 2.

Comment: @CanGencer, thank you for the answers. Yes I've already read that default number of partitions is 271 and didn't get your question at the begining. So I just increased the capacity of journal without any other changes of default values `config.getMapEventJournalConfig(Constants.IMAP_TAGS_POSITIONS_BUFFER).setCapacity(EventJournalConfig.DEFAULT_CAPACITY * 10).setEnabled(true);`. If you say that it is only ~369 entries in the journal - it could be a reason. I also will try to increase localParallelism, but I need to keep the order of received messages.

Comment: Guys... I increased the localParallelism and capacity of mapJournal, but it is still slowing. The processing works fast at the start of application and slows down after some time. Need I clean or reset mapJournal after each event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the using of single IMap (and map journal) by multiple jobs. Map journal was producing events like a batch with delay, but not as stream.

Solved. Thanks!